# Remove Factory Girl from backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I'm trying to clean up the backtraces I get in my Rails application. Here is the one I'm working on right now:

```
 Failure/Error: attributes_for :bookmark, :invalid

 ArgumentError:
   Trait not registered: invalid
 # /Users/amandacrawford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@autocato/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find'
 # /Users/amandacrawford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@autocato/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
 # (... more lines from Factory Girl ...)
 # /Users/amandacrawford/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@autocato/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
 # ./spec/controllers/bookmarks_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/bookmarks_controller_spec.rb:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I want all but the last two lines removed from the stack trace. So far, this is my config:

```
# config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line =~ /spring/ }
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line =~ /factory_girl\/registry/ }
```

I know that if the application stack trace is empty after the silencers are applied, it will show everything, but in this case, there should still be the last two lines.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the answer to my own question today - when one of my specs had the full backtrace removed, I realized it was RSpec that was cleaning up the backtrace in this case.

RSpec also [has a way to remove gems from the backtrace](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/excluding-lines-from-the-backtrace) - add the following to your `rails_helper.rb`:

```
config.filter_gems_from_backtrace('spring', 'factory_girl')
```